# How to add onClick listener for each row to dynamically generated table in JavaFX 2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I have my tableview generated dynamically and filled out with data from my database in postgresql. That part works fine. Now I would like to be able to have onclick listener for each row in that table, so whenever I click on a row, another window pops out, for example. Moreover, I would like to know not the number of the row clicked, but information from that row. So for example in output:

[image]

When I click lets say on July, I want to have 111.0 value stored somewhere. I would be happy with simply printing it out for now. (picture is not mine, I used it only for demonstrative purposes)

Here is my code:

```
//TABLE VIEW AND DATA
private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
private TableView tableview;

//MAIN EXECUTOR
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

//CONNECTION DATABASE
public void buildData(){

      data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      try{
       Connection c = DBConnect.getDBConnection();

        ResultSet rs = getRecords();

        /**********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         **********************************/
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                     return new SimpleObjectProperty(param.getValue().get(j));                        
                }                    
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col); 
           // System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        /********************************
         * Data added to ObservableList *
         ********************************/
        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
         //   System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);

        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        tableview.setItems(data);

      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
      }



}





  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    //TableView
    tableview = new TableView();
    buildData();

    //Main Scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(tableview);        

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

   public ResultSet getRecords() throws SQLException
{
    Connection connection = getDBConnection();
    java.sql.Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");

    return rs;
}
```

I tried with this code but it does not work (error says that I cannot cast Object to UserClass.

```
  UserClass selectedUser = new UserClass();
        final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
       tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new         ChangeListener()
       {
           public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue,Object newValue)
           {
               UserClass selectedUser = (UserClass)newValue;
               ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
               content.putString(selectedUser.toString());
               clipboard.setContent(content); 
           }
       });
```

If there is any other, preferably easier and more straightforward way I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you can do so: add cell factory for columns of the TableView, and for each cell there is a link on TableRow, via:

```
public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<TableRow> tableRowProperty
```

A TableRow object has all these useful properties, such as setting on<...>Click listeners.

Each cell has them all too.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and I think it will work. Yet I am not sure about implementation. Can you please describe it a little bit more? It would be perfect if you could provide some code with description.